# Is there a reason not to store data from messaging app in android sms databases?

Tags: android

I built a messaging app that allows users to send and receive sms messages along with other types of messages. Right now I am storing all of the sent and received messages in Android's default databases that hold all sms messages. (content://sms/inbox and content://sms/sent) Is there any reason why this would be a bad idea? I know I could use my own database but unless there is a reason I should I like the simplicity of using the database that already exists on the users phone.

Also will all android devices from all manufacturers have their sms databases in the same place that I will be able to access or will their be issues across different devices and manufacturers?

Comment: one thing to note, is to make sure you havent left it open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: You should write your app in such a way that user won't be able to delete messages which weren't created by your app.

Comment: The idea is that my application would be an sms replacement app, I assumed synchronization with the existing app would be preferred. But that is something to take into consideration

Comment: As you are creating a replacement app for messaging, and are putting messages into the existing database, the last thing you would want, is someone being able to delete a targets messages. Sql injection prevention is important for ALL databases. I just bring it up, as you are connecting to their message database, and the last thing you want is someone losing messages that are not necessarily anything to do with you app. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection . Its mainly an issue if you are inserting the message directly into the DB. `INSERT INTO messagetable VALUES(msgeText)` or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly ok to use existing databases. This is the way many existing messaging apps work.

Comment: I should have asked this is my question but will all android devices from all manufacturers have their sms databases in the same place that I will be able to access or will their be issues across different devices and manufacturers?

Comment: Generally the behavior should be consistent across different manufacturers.

Comment: Thank you @DamianJeżewski I suppose I will have to test across multiple manufacturers to be sure

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for all users, but I imagine a significant number of them (myself included) would object to having non-SMS messages stored in the same database as SMS messages.

If I used your app, and then opened up the stock SMS app and saw non-SMS messages there, I'd go on a rampage.

Comment: Well you would be using my app to send sms messages as a replacement for your default sms application. The hope was that if you decide to uninstall the app you wouldn't lose your messages.

Comment: I understand that, but my point is that if, for whatever reason, I open an SMS app, I should see ONLY SMS messages.  If your app combines SMS messages with messages from another source and displays them seamlessly, then that's fine, but it if screws up how other apps show messages (for example, by inserting non-SMS messages into the SMS message database), then bad.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your input, my application would be doing the first, storing them seamlessly.

Comment: There's a difference between displaying seamlessly and storing seamlessly.  Displaying seamlessly doesn't affect anything else on the device.  Storing them seamlessly by using the SMS database will affect other apps, and not in a good way.  Suddenly my stock SMS app will be displaying (for example) Google Talk messages, and that's not expected or desired (in most cases).  If I want to see SMS messages, I use the SMS app, if I want to see all messages, I use an app like yours (that doesn't screw up the SMS database).

Comment: Right now my application is doing both, storing and displaying messages seamlessly

Comment: In my opinion, displaying seamlessly is great, storing seamlessly is not, unless you're using your own database to do it, for the reasons I've stated above.